# Pagination in Slider, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Any ideas how to make paginantion in slider using jquery like in google? For example, when i will have 1000 photos in slider, the numbers below slider will slide like in google.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZL6j.png)

Comment: Questions that ask for offsite tutorials / resources like this aren't the place for SO - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

If your inquiry is about Pagination in general, I recommend using DataTables Plugin. You can modify styles or scripts to make it look nicer according to your specifications.

Here are the steps to use this plugin -

1. Includes these files in your project
   CSS FILE - //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css 
   JS FILE - //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
2. Configure JQUERY DataTable inside your Project
   $('#TableID').DataTable();
3. Tweak and twist CSS and JS to change look and feel of the DataTable.

Hope that helps!